# Add page numbers to HTML generated with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm generating a bunch of HTML docs with Sphinx. Is there an easy way to add page numbers to the HTML files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you would want to do this, but you could try something like:

1. Create a simple Sphinx extension
2. set up a global page counter in your conf.py or in your extension
3. handle the [html-page-context](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/appapi.html#event-html-page-context) event, passing the current page counter into the context parameter.

I haven't used that event in this way before, but it seems like it ***should*** work.

Comment: The reason was that the client requested it.  After I didn't get an answer here I solved the problem by replying, "I don't know of an easy way to do that."  I'm just going to go ahead and assume your answer works and accept it.  If anyone finds out that this answer doesn't work, leave a comment and I'll unaccept it.